# Installing Laravel PJAX

Tags: php, laravel, pjax

I am trying to install PJAX for LAravel 5.1 and having an issue getting the middleware installed.

The jquery pjax is installed fine and I can tell it is working. My issue then was that the url's were changing and when the refresh on the browser was pushed the page was refreshing the ajax only component. This I understand should happen so I then found the JacobBennet PJAX for Laravel.

"jacobbennett/pjax": "0.*" to compose.json and updated and I can see the relevant items have been installed.

Then I added the JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware to my app/Http/Kernel.php

My Kernel.php $middleware array looks like this now.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware
];
```

However when I try now open the page I get,

> PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'App\Http\JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware'

I am sure this is a simple this I am getting wrong. I have search for hours but my brain is failing on me ;)

Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change that last line to

```
 JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware::class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I did that and tried it before.  I get `Class App\Http\JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware does not exist`

Comment: Oh, ok. I think you have to look into your vendor folder for the class `PjaxMiddleware` and then change it to that path.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the \ in from of the line.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.0* version there is strip slash is there is middleware class.And also you miss "\" in starting of `JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware`.

so change your middleware code with this one.

```
   protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \JacobBennett\Pjax\PjaxMiddleware::class
];
```

Thats it!!